# HTML rendering before for-loop finishes executing, only first item in for-loop showing

Tags: javascript, for-loop, socket.io, rendering

I am trying to render an html page that contains all of the posts that a user has received. Right now the issue I am having (shown under Way 1) is that when I call the function renderPosts after the web socket is received, only the first post in the array is rendered (the array has more than one post in it).

On the other hand, Way 2 in which I have no for loop and instead manually render each post works in that all four posts are rendered. But I need to be able to work with an arbitrary number of posts which is why I need to use the for loop.

I am using socket.io and javascript.

**Way 1:**

```
socket.on('postsToRender', function(arrayOfPostsToRender) {
   renderPosts(arrayOfPostsToRender);
});

function renderPosts(arrayOfPostsToRender) {
   for (var index = 0; index < arrayOfPostsToRender.length; index++) {
      renderPost(arrayOfPostsToRender[index]);
   }
}

function renderPost(postToRender) {
   var feed = document.getElementById("feed");
   var postContent = document.createTextNode(postToRender.content);
   var post = document.createElement("div");
   post.appendChild(postContent);
   feed.appendChild(post);
}
```

**Way 2:**

```
socket.on('postsToRender', function(arrayOfPostsToRender) {
   renderPost(arrayOfPostsToRender[0]);
   renderPost(arrayOfPostsToRender[1]);
   renderPost(arrayOfPostsToRender[2]);
   renderPost(arrayOfPostsToRender[3]);
});

function renderPost(postToRender) {
   var feed = document.getElementById("feed");
   var postContent = document.createTextNode(postToRender.content);
   var post = document.createElement("div");
   post.appendChild(postContent);
   feed.appendChild(post);
}
```

Comment: The fact that your loop variable "index" is not declared with `var` makes me sad.

Comment: I changed it. Not sure if you were being ironic though.

Comment: No, I wasn't being ironic. Because you lacked a `var` declaration, the variable was a global, so if any of the functions called from inside the `for` loop *also* used the global `index`, it would screw up the loop.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(arrayOfPostsToRender);` and let us know what is shown on the console? Right after function `renderPosts(arrayOfPostsToRender) {`

Comment: Pointy's recommendation solved the issue. I was using index in multiple for loops on my code without declaring them as local variables so all of my loops were getting messed up.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function renderPosts(arrayOfPostsToRender) {
   for (var index = 0; index < arrayOfPostsToRender.length; index++) {
      (function(i){
         renderPost(arrayOfPostsToRender[i]);
      })(index);
   }
}
```